# Uniform scaling of a Table of Graphics objects?

Tags: graphics

```
Row[Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2^k, 1}]], {k, 0, 5}]]
```

yields

[image]

However, I'd like uniform scaling of the rectangles, i.e., each rectangle should look twice the width (but same height) as its predecessor. How can I force "absolute sizing" here?

Second, how can I align the bottoms of the rectangles? I tried inserting `Alignment->Bottom` in several spots, none of which worked.

Comment: I also find it strange that it is keeping the *widths* constant, but scaling the *heights* even though it is the widths that are increasing with k.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Row will resize anything that doesn't already have a size attribute set.  By setting the imageheight for each graphics object but keeping the width Automatic, you get what you are looking for:

```
Row[Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2^k, 1}], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 25}, PlotRangePadding -> None], {k, 0, 5}]]
```

[image]

Since they are all the same height, they are all automatically aligned properly.  If they weren't, I couldn't get Row to align them properly, but Grid did the trick easily.

```
Grid[{Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2^k, 1}],PlotRangePadding -> None], {k, 0, 5}]},  Alignment -> {Left, Bottom}]
```

gives this:
[image]

Comment: My experience is that you can also control the spacing between elements a lot better with Grid than with Row.  (Are we all agreed that GraphicsGrid is a trainwreck?)

Comment: Yes, `GraphicsGrid` = trainwreck with maximal carnage, IMO.

Comment: Jason, I still don't get why the first rectangle won't cooperate: `Grid[{Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2^-k, 1}], PlotRangePadding -> None], {k, 0, 5}]}, Alignment -> {Left, Bottom}]`

Comment: @texasAUtiger, from what I can tell, Grid and Row will resize anything that doesn't have its ImageSize set already.  So I would still set them so they all have the same height: 
Grid[{Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0,0},{2^(-k),1}],PlotRangePadding->None,ImageSize->{Automatic,25}],{k,0,5}]},Alignment->{Left,Bottom}]

Comment: Jason, try e.g. `Row[(*list*), Spacer[5]]`

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the `PlotRange` explicitly as follows:

```
Row[Table[
  Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2^k, 1}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2^5}, {0, 1}}], {k, 0, 5}]]
```

[image: example]

Comment: I'd need to avoid the large gaps of white space in this solution.